# Fingerprint scanner (Futronic FS82 fingerprint scanner) integration for PHP application

Tags: javascript, java, php, applet, fingerprint

I am developing a **Web based Biometric registration portal** (PHP+MySQL+JavaScript) where a student will be registered with his personal info and his fingerprint. The fingerprint will be taken trough **Futronic FS82 fingerprint scanner**. The device supplier company *Futronic* (http://www.futronic-tech.com) are providing SDK for VB.NET and JAVA.

This device captures the finger image and saves the image in a specific folder and search any user with the fingerprint from that specific folder.

Now I am trying to integrate everything in my web portal where there will be a button like "Scan". When someone clicks that button, automatically the user will be asked to provide fingerprint and I need to save it in my specified folder. And again when I will search the user with his fingerprint, it will search from that folder and give me the result.........

I am not getting any idea how to do it. Please guide me....Do I need to make a java applet or something? How can I do that?

Comment: PHP has [Direct IO](http://id1.php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php) extension that I think worth for you to try. There's also packages that offer a communication within serial port that exists on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PHP is server-side, you cant just click a button, and let it wait for input.

So if the fingerprint scanner can print a value thats unique to each finger (like most barcode scanners do), you can just do an input field, and have that POST to a PHP script, that will verify the value, will all the already saved onces.

If it dosn't return a value, you will most likely need to create a VB.NET or JAVA "plugin", that can handle this, and either post a value it self, or make it return the value of the finger thats scanned.